# Follow and Unfollow with Ajax works fine, but having issue with display

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

The ajax function for the follow and unfollow features on the webapp I'm developing works fine, but the issue is that when I click on either 'Follow' or 'Unfollow' button on any of the displayed list of my followers, the follow or unfollow button ONLY toggle without page refresh for the first follower on the displayed list of followers. If I click follow or unfollow on any other displayed followers except the first one on the list, I would have to refresh the page to see the follow/unfollow button changed. 
In summary, clicking follow/unfollow button on any follower except the first on my displayed list of followers doesn't toggle the follow/unfollow button without page refresh.

**PHP Code**

```
    $sql = "SELECT users.firstname, users.lastname, users.avatar, users.username FROM users INNER JOIN follows ON users.username=follows.user1 WHERE user2='$u' ORDER BY RAND()";
    $result_select = mysqli_query($db_connect, $sql);
    // Check if user has followers
    $numrows = mysqli_num_rows($result_select);
        if($numrows < 1){
        echo '<div id="nav-follow">';
          echo '<ul>';
           echo '<li>'.'<a href="http://localhost:8080/app/follow_page.php?u='.$u.'" class="selected">'.'Followers'.'</a>'.'</li>';
           echo '<li>'.'<a href="http://localhost:8080/app/following_page.php?u='.$u.'">'.'Following'.'</a>'.'</li>';
          echo '</ul>';
        echo '</div>';
        echo '<div id="followerList" style="height:60px; text-align:center; vertical-align: middle; font-size:20px; color:white;">';        
        echo "I don't have any follower yet. If I start following others, they will also follow me.";
        echo '</div></div>'; 
            include_once("template_pageRight.php");

            exit();
        }

?><?php
        echo '<div id="nav-follow">';
          echo '<ul>';
           echo '<li>'.'<a href="http://localhost:8080/app/follow_page.php?u='.$u.'" class="selected">'.'Followers'.'</a>'.'</li>';
           echo '<li>'.'<a href="http://localhost:8080/app/following_page.php?u='.$u.'">'.'Following'.'</a>'.'</li>';
          echo '</ul>';
        echo '</div>'.'<br />';
    // Fetch the user row from the query above
    $row = array();
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result_select))
        $rows[] = $row;
    foreach($rows as $row){
        $followUsername = $row['username'];



?><?php
    $following = false;


    if($u == $log_username && $user_ok == true){
        $follow_check = "SELECT id FROM follows WHERE user1='$log_username' AND user2='$followUsername' LIMIT 1";
        if(mysqli_num_rows(mysqli_query($db_connect, $follow_check)) > 0){
            $following = true;  
        }
    } elseif($u != $log_username && $user_ok == true){
        $follow_check = "SELECT id FROM follows WHERE user1='$log_username' AND user2='$followUsername' LIMIT 1";
        if(mysqli_num_rows(mysqli_query($db_connect, $follow_check)) > 0){
            $following = true;  
        }
    }
?><?php
    //$followUsername_Btn = "";
    if($following == true){
        $followUsername_Btn = '<button onclick="followUsernameToggle(\'unfollow\',\''.$followUsername.'\',\'followUsernameBtn\')">Unfollow</button>';
        } elseif($followUsername != $log_username && $following == false && $user_ok == true) {
            $followUsername_Btn = '<button onclick="followUsernameToggle(\'follow\',\''.$followUsername.'\',\'followUsernameBtn\')">Follow</button>';
        } else {
            $followUsername_Btn = '<button disabled>Me</button>';
        }
?><?php 

        echo '<div id="followerList">';
            echo '<a class="image" href="http://localhost:8080/app/user_audio.php?u='.$followUsername.'"><img src="user/'.$followUsername.'/'.$row['avatar'].'" alt="'.$followUsername.'">'.'<br />';
            echo '<div id="fuserName">'.$row["firstname"].' '.$row["lastname"].'</a>'.'</div>';
            echo '<span id="followUsernameBtn">'.$followUsername_Btn.'</span>';   
        echo '</div><br />';
} 
?>
```

**jQuery**

```
function followUsernameToggle(type, user, elem) {
    var conf = confirm("Please confirm.");
    if (conf != true) {
        return false;
    }
    //_(elem).innerHTML = 'please wait...';
    var xhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        // code for modern browsers
        xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        // code for IE6, IE5
        xhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            if (this.responseText == "follow_ok") {
                _(elem).innerHTML = '<button onclick="followUsernameToggle(\'unfollow\',\'<?php echo $followUsername; ?>\',\'followUsernameBtn\')">Unfollow</button>';
            } else if (this.responseText == "unfollow_ok") {
                _(elem).innerHTML = '<button onclick="followUsernameToggle(\'follow\',\'<?php echo $followUsername; ?>\',\'followUsernameBtn\')">Follow</button>';
            } else {
                alert(this.responseText);
                _(elem).innerHTML = 'Try again later';
            }
        }
    };
    xhttp.open("POST", "php_parsers/follow_system.php", true);
    xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xhttp.send("type=" + type + "&user=" + user);
}
```

**follow_system.php**

```
<?php 
$sql = "SELECT countrycode, mobile FROM users WHERE username='$log_username' LIMIT 1";
$query = mysqli_query($db_connect, $sql);
if(mysqli_num_rows($query) > 0){
    $row = mysqli_fetch_row($query);
    $countrycode = $row[0];
    $mobile = $row[1];
}
?><?php
$user = mysqli_real_escape_string($db_connect, $_POST['user']);
//$type = mysqli_real_escape_string($db_connect, $_POST['type']);
if($_POST['type'] == "follow" && isset($_POST['user'])){
$sql = "INSERT INTO follows (user1, user2, countrycode, mobile, datefollowed) VALUES ('$log_username','$user','$countrycode','$mobile',now())"; 
            $query = mysqli_query($db_connect, $sql);
            mysqli_close($db_connect);
            echo "follow_ok"; 
            exit();
        } else if($_POST['type'] == "unfollow" && isset($_POST['user'])){
            $sql = "DELETE FROM follows WHERE user1='$log_username' AND user2='$user' AND countrycode='$countrycode' AND mobile='$mobile'";
            $query = mysqli_query($db_connect, $sql);
            mysqli_close($db_connect);
            echo "unfollow_ok";
            exit();
        }   

?>
```

As I said, looking at the below picture, when I click Follow or Unfollow on FollowerB or C, the button doesn't toggle and I have to refresh the page to see the change in button from follow to unfollow and vice versa. But when I click on FollowerA which is at the top of the list, the button toggle without refresh.
Please I need help on why it's only the first follower on the list that works properly.

[Follow_Unfollow_Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Epo6y.jpg)

Comment: your code is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. Use parameterised queries to better protect your data from being stolen, deleted, corrupted or otherwise attacked by malicious users.

Comment: Please anyone with possible clue or solution to this question? @ADyson Noted.

Comment: Okay, I solved it! The problem is the third argument in my jquery - elem. I was using 'followUsernameBtn' to represent this element for all the displayed followers. Now I'm using the database ID of each user as the elem and everything works fine now.

Comment: Glad you solved it. Please also heed my warning about SQL Injection, otherwise your database will be very vulnerable. If you don't understand what it is, please Google it. It means someone could potentially steal or delete all the information in your database in one command simply by entering the right command into one of your input text boxes. Here is a humorous but very accurate description of what can happen: http://bobby-tables.com/